# jquery ajax not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#edit-my-username").click(function() {
                    $("#my-username").html('<input type="text" id="new-username" value="<?php echo $my_username; ?>"> <button class="my-button small-btn" id="submit-my-username">Submit</button>');
                });
                $("#submit-my-username").click(function() {
                    var user = "<?php echo $userid; ?>";
                    var edit_field = "username";
                    var edit_content = $("#new-username").val();
                    if(edit_content !== ''){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "edit-user.php",
                            data: {user: user, field: edit_field, content: edit_content},
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html){
                                $("#my-username").html(html);
                            }
                        });
                    }return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't submit. Firebug see's no XHR when the button is clicked. I'm not exactly confident with JS/jQ.. where am I going wrong?

Comment: you are binding a click event to an element previously created after the dom is ready. you need to use event delegation, means the on('click') handler to attach the click event dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dynamically adding `#submit-my-username` the click handler is not binded on page load.

```
$("#submit-my-username").click(function() {
```

Change the click handler to following

```
$("body").on( "click", "#submit-my-username", function() {
```

Comment: This did it, thanks. I'll have to keep in mind the thing about dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you add html via javascript, in your case jquery, the **click** event (and any other trigger events) do not works.
You have to use **on** event, or **live** event, but the last one is deprecated.

For example:

```
$("#submit-my-username").live('click'. function()
$("#submit-my-username").on('click', function()
```

Answer (score 0):

When page load,jquery ready funciton executed.The section 'Submit' does not exist,so '$("#submit-my-username").click(function() {}' script not works.

I think you should add onclick event in 'Submit' distinctly.

such as :

```
<button class="my-button small-btn" id="submit-my-username" onclick='func()'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use .live() method, however it is now deprecated. instead of that you can use .on()

```
$("#my-username").on('click', '#submit-my-username', function(event) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for mis-interpreting your question.Below code can be user to submit form using jquery.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
//your code
});
```

Hope this is the answer to your question.